# Magento: Index Management Page Just shows Blank

Tags: magento, indexing, admin

The index Management page from back end is just showing a blank page. I am not using any custom theme for admin side but it is not showing up.

The header and footer and all other content of the page is there but the re-indexing table is not showing, as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be caused by unexpected termination of previous reindex. You can try make reindex manually via cmd/terminal (go to magento root/shell and type php indexer.php --reindexall) and then try to go to this page again.

Also, you can enable errors displaying in magento via editing index.php - uncomment line 77 and change line 73 to `if (!isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {` - this may give you more info about error

Answer (score 8):

If tou have GeoIp extension, you need to change in the file app/code/community/Openstream/GeoIP/etc/config.xml

```
   <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <index>
                    <geoip>
                        <file>openstream/geoip.xml</file>
                    </geoip>
                </index>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
```

Comment: In my case above was the case. GEOIP has never bothered update their XML or I am not sure if anyone has reported this

Comment: It works for me, I have upgraded Magento version 1.6 to 1.9 and having same problem. I also have GEOIP extension in my Magento installation.
With the help of above solution it has fixed - Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I upgrade Magento 1.7.02 to 1.9.01 , I checked the files there is some code is missing on that file

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\index.xml
```

I compared the file ,this code is missing so add this at bottom of index.xml

```
 <adminhtml_process_list>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="index/adminhtml_process" name="process" />
  </reference>
</adminhtml_process_list>
```

I hope it will show the whole page not blank .

Comment: This one fixed my issue. Thanks! 
I honestly don't know how Mage could miss something like that..

Answer (score 3):

I found out the solution. The problem is caused by the extension. So if any one is facing this problem disable your extensions one by one and you will found out the extension which is causing the problem. In my case it was geoip of openstream extension.

Answer (score 3):

My index management page is also blank between the header and footer after updating to Magento CE 1.9.2.2. None of the above answers resolved this for me. Here are the things I tried:

---

**Tried #1:** Enabling error logging in "System > Config > Developer".

**Result:** Both `exception.log` or `system.log` are empty.

---

**Tried #2:** Enable `DEVELOPER_MODE` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` from `index.php`.

**Result:** No change.

---

**Tried #3:** Raise memory limit in `.htaccess` file.

**Result:** No change. The header/footer should not load if the page generator runs out of memory.

---

**Tried #4:** Disable all custom modules.

**Result:** No change.

---

**Tried #5:** Re-index via shell.

```
cd shell
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

All indices appear to succeed:

```
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

**Result:** No change. Checking index status shows all are pending:

```
php indexer.php --status
```

Output:

```
Product Attributes:                 Pending
Product Prices:                     Pending
Catalog URL Rewrites:               Pending
Category Products:                  Pending
Catalog Search Index:               Pending
Stock Status:                       Pending
Tag Aggregation Data:               Pending
```

I noticed there is no `Product Flat Data Index` listed.

---

**Tried #6:** Truncated the database table `catalog_product_flat_1` and tried to force a reindex manually:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

**Result:** No change. Does not show in status list either.

---

I'm pretty much stumped. The site works, but what could be causing the index management page to half-load?

---

### The Solution

Turns out the `mage` tool for updating fails a lot since Magento 1.9.2.x and can leave modules incomplete or broken. This is what happened. I don't recommend using this process anymore.

2924 files were incorrect after trying to update from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.2 using the `mage` tool.

This was confirmed because I removed the entire filesystem and replaced it with a fresh ZIP of Magento 1.9.2.2. The diff showed exactly what the `mage` tool failed to update properly.

I saved it to a gist for reference:
https://gist.github.com/brendanfalkowski/257a33516d672ec57e00

The index management worked after getting a fresh (full) version of Magento 1.9.2.2.

Revised my Field Manual for updating Magento to stop recommending the `mage` method: http://manuals.gravitydept.com/platforms/magento/update

Answer (score 1):

Check that the module output is not disabled under `System > Configuration > Advanced > Mage_Index`

Comment: It's enabled. Also checked  /app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml. No changes there.

Comment: I vaguely remember having once come across some weirdness with this setting. Try disabling - save config then enabling it again and save config to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, after debug a lot of things I found that _afterLoadCollection() function has used count() method, count method does not work when we have a large amount of data, instead of we can use getSize() method.

Directly we cannot edit the core file of Magento because it's not a good habit.

For a quick solution we can add the below parameter in the index.php(root) file.

ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

If you want to debug then open below file and find **_afterLoadCollection()** funtion. In which you can see this line "**$item->getUnprocessedEventsCollection()->count()**".

**app\code\core\Mage\Index\Block\Adminhtml\Process\Grid.php**

I think this information can help someone.