# Blank Index Management page in Magento after upgrading from 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, upgrade, magento-1.8

I recently upgraded a site running Magento CE 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.1.0.

After doing this the Index Management Page in the Admin panel is showing a blank screen, as shown here: [Magento: Index Management Page Just shows Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285181/magento-index-management-page-just-shows-blank)

I can reindex the site through ssh (shell/indexer.php --reindexall) and this works fine, so I know the problem isn't with the database itself.

I've Googled this and found other people having similar problems and suggesting to disable extensions etc. I've disabled everything except core Mage stuff and it still does the same thing. I've done all the usual other stuff such as clearing the cache, browser cookies, etc. Still the same.

The upgrade process we used was as follows:

1. installing a clean copy of 1.8 on a development server
2. moving files (extensions, js/css, images, theme files) from 1.7 to 1.8
3. making a copy of the 1.7 database on the development server. updating app/etc/local.xml to point the 1.8 installation at the database from 1.7 (which contains all the product/customer data we needed to retain).
4. run the 1.8 site in a browser whilst upgrade scripts run.

Comment: Have you resolve this problem?I am facing this error too.

Comment: No. We resorted to using ssh reindexing - not ideal but couldn't get the page to work. It seems to have all the templates that it needs.

Answer (score 2):

I upgrade Magento 1.7.02 to 1.9.01 ,
I checked the files there is some code is missing on that file

```
   app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\index.xml
```

I compared the file ,this code is missing so add this at bottom of index.xml

```
<adminhtml_process_list>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="index/adminhtml_process" name="process" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_process_list>
```

I hope it will show the whole page not blank .

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Works for me :) PS: I'm not sure if the system was updated, but works.